# How to use a pattern for a file path with OPENROWSET in Azure SQL?

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

I want to match all csv files under "testpath/test", which in the format "Test_2023_08_08.csv", in Azure SQL Database.

```
SELECT TOP 10 *
FROM OPENROWSET( BULK 'testpath/test/Test_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9].csv'
)
AS row
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(row.filepath(1),row.filepath(2),row.filepath(3)) BETWEEN @DATE1 AND DATE2;
```

But seems not work.

Comment: `OPENROWSET` expected a *literal*, you can't pass it a pattern and expect it to consume *all* files that match that pattern. The problem also have *nothing* to do with Regex, you aren't trying to use regex here.

Comment: It only works that way in Synapse Serverless. Not in standard Azure SQL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/develop-openrowset

Comment: Are you using the Azure synapse Serverless pool?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of providing a pattern to OPENROWSET that way, you can use a wildcard character (*) to load multiple files that match a naming pattern. Could you try something like below? Does this approach satisfies your requirements?

```
INSERT INTO MyTable
SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK 'mycontainer/Test_2023_08*.csv',
DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage',
FORMAT = 'CSV',
FORMATFILE='mycontainer/format.fmt',
FORMATFILE_DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureBlobStorage'
) AS DataFile;
```

Comment: Can't use wildcard.

Comment: The samples say `BULK()` support wildcard for Parquet on S3 though, need to check on other data storage sources. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#l-use-openrowset-to-access-several-parquet-files-using-s3-compatible-object-storage